My jest cant find\resolve absolute imports
I did my best. I tried ts-jest, many configs, different aliases, etc.
My jest cant resolve any module. Everything is good when i use relative imports.
I need to make jest import my modules somehow

"jest": "^29.7.0", node = v20.17.0

##################################################################################################
Error:
src/shared/lib/getRootDir/getRootDir.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'shared/lib/getRootDir/getRootDir' from 'src/testing/resolvers/snapshotResolver.ts'

    > 1 | import { getRootDir } from 'shared/lib/getRootDir/getRootDir';
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | module.exports = {
      4 |     testPathForConsistencyCheck: 'some/example.test.ts',

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
      at Object.require (src/testing/resolvers/snapshotResolver.ts:1:1)

Error: Cannot find module 'shared/lib/getRootDir/getRootDir'

Jest config:
import type { Config } from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
    clearMocks: true,
    bail: 3,
    rootDir: './',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'cjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'],
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>src/**/*(*.)@(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['\\\\node_modules\\\\'],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['\\\\node_modules\\\\'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
     '^shared(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/shared$1',
    },
    roots: ['<rootDir>'],
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    snapshotResolver: '<rootDir>/src/testing/resolvers/snapshotResolver.ts',
};

export default config;


Ts-config:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ES2021",
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["./src/*"],
        }
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "CommonJS"
        }
    }
}


webpack resolve:
 extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
 preferAbsolute: true,
 modules: [paths.src, 'node_modules'],
 mainFiles: ['index'],
 alias: {},

resolver.ts:
import { getRootDir } from 'shared/lib/getRootDir/getRootDir';

module.exports = {
    testPathForConsistencyCheck: 'some/example.test.ts',

    resolveSnapshotPath: (testPath: string, snapshotExtension: string) => {
        const rootDir = getRootDir(testPath);
        const pathToSnapshotsDir = `${rootDir}\\src\\testing\\__snapshots__`;
        const newSnapshotFilename = testPath.split('\\').at(-1);

        const path = testPath.includes('src')
            ? `${pathToSnapshotsDir}\\${newSnapshotFilename}`
            : testPath;

        return path.replace(/\.test\.([tj]sx?)/, `${snapshotExtension}.$1`);
    },

    resolveTestPath: (snapshotFilePath: string, snapshotExtension: string) =>
        snapshotFilePath.replace(snapshotExtension, '.test'),
};

